# Reusing Slick's DB driver code in data access layer

Tags: scala, slick, data-access

I'm trying to wrap my head around data access with Slick 3.0. After consulting various github examples, I've came with following design.

**A singleton Slick object where the DataSource and Driver instances are injected**

```
class Slick(dataSource: DataSource, val driver: JdbcDriver)  {

  val db = driver.api.Database.forDataSource(dataSource)     

}
```

**A trait per DB table where the mappings are defined**

The trait is mixed in the upper layer where the queries are constructed.

```
trait RecipeTable {

  protected val slick: Slick

  // the ugly import that have to be added when Slick API is used
  import slick.driver.api._

  type RecipeRow = (Option[Long], String)

  class RecipeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[RecipeRow](tag, "recipe") {

    def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")

    def * = (id, name)    
  }

  protected val recipes = TableQuery[RecipeTable]    
}
```

Now there's obvious drawback that in every `*Table` trait and also in every place where that is mixed in I need to duplicate import `slick.driver.api._` in order to have all Slick's stuff in scope.

This something I'd like to avoid. Ideally the import will be defined only once and reused in downstream components.

Could you please suggest the a design that addresses such a duplication?

I was mainly inspired by [this](https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest) example, however the imports are duplicated there as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That "ugly" import is actually a good thing about slick's design. But your way of slick usage can be improved as following,

Create a trait which will provide `JdbcDriver`

```
package demo.slick.dbl

trait SlickDriverComponent {
  val driver: JdbcDriver
}

trait SlickDBComponent extends SlickDriverComponent {
  val db: driver.api.Database
}
```

Now define your DAO traits as traits dependant on this trait,

```
package demo.slick.dao

import demo.slick.dbl.SlickDBComponent

trait RecipeDAO { self: SlickDBComponent =>

  import driver.api._

  type RecipeRow = (Option[Long], String)

  class RecipeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[RecipeRow](tag, "recipe") {

    def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")

    def * = (id, name)    
  }

  val recipes = TableQuery[RecipeTable]

  def get5Future = db.run(recipes.take(5).result)

}
```

When it comes to actually connecting with DB and doing things,

```
package demo.slick.dbl

trait MySqlDriverProvider extends SlickDriverComponent {          
  val driver = slick.driver.MySQLDriver
}

object MySqlDBConnection extends MySqlDriverProvider {
  val connection = driver.api.Database.forConfig("mysql")
}

trait MySqlDBProvider extends SlickDBComponent {          
  val driver = slick.driver.MySQLDriver
  val db: Database = MySqlDBConnection.connection
}

trait PostgresDriverProvider extends SlickDriverComponent {          
  val driver = slick.driver.PostgresDriver
}

object PostgresDBConnection extends PostgresDriverProvider {
  val connection = driver.api.Database.forConfig("postgres")
}

trait PostgresDBProvider extends SlickDBComponent {
  val driver = slick.driver.PostgresDriver
  val db: Database = PostgresDBConnection.connection
}
```

Now finally define your DAO objects as follows,

```
package demo.slick.dao

import demo.slick.dbl.MySqlDBProvider

object MySqlRecipeDAO extends RecipeDAO with MySqlDBProvider

object PostgresRecipeDAO extends RecipeDAO with PostgresDBProvider
```

Now, you can use these as follows,

```
pakcage demo.slick

import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import demo.slick.RecipeDAO

object App extends Application {
  val recipesFuture = MysqlRecipeDAO.get5Future

  recipesFuture.onComplete({
    case Success(seq) => println("Success :: found :: " + seq)
    case Failure(ex) => println("Failure :: failed :: " + ex.getMessage)
  })
}
```

Now... as we all know that different databases have different sets of functionalities and hence the "things" available to you will depend upon the driver being used.

So that need to ugly import every time is so that you can write your DAO traits once and then be able to use them with whatever database specific driver implementation you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. While I doubt duplicating the ``import driver.api._`` is actually a good thing, it seems to be the only way to go with Slick. For sure, there must be arguments to design the API like this, but still I don't get why having just ``TableQuery[T]`` instance is not enough to construct the queries (given the fact that standard SQL constructs are supported by *all* drivers).

Comment: Well... when you use `java.time.ZoneDateTime` you have to import it wherever you need... its is the same principle. Most of Slick's insides are designed as `implicits` which can be imported or changed whenever needed without affecting any thing else.